# what RSpec approach could I use for this requirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, rspec-rails

Background:  So I have roughly (Ruby on Rails app)

```
class A
   def calculate_input_datetimes
      # do stuff to calculate datetimes - then for each one identified
      process_datetimes(my_datetime_start, my_datetime_end)
   end

   def process_datetimes(input_datetime_start, input_datetime_end)
      # do stuff
   end
end
```

So:

- I want to test that calculate_input_datetimes algorithms are working 
  and calculating the correct datetimes to pass to process_datetimes
- I know I can STUB out process_datetimes so that it's code won't be 
  involved in the test

**QUESTION**:  How can I setup the rspec test however so I can specifically 
test that the correct datestimes were attempted to be passed over to 
process_datetimes,  So for a given spec test that process_datetimes was 
called three (3) times say with the following parameters passed:

- 2012-03-03T00:00:00+00:00, 2012-03-09T23:59:59+00:00
- 2012-03-10T00:00:00+00:00, 2012-03-16T23:59:59+00:00
- 2012-03-17T00:00:00+00:00, 2012-03-23T23:59:59+00:00

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `should_receive` and specifying what arguments are expected using `with`, for example

```
a.should_receive(:process_datetimes).with(date1,date2)
a.should_receive(:process_datetimes).with(date3,date4)
a.calculate_input_datetimes
```

There are more examples in the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-8/docs/message-expectations), for example you can use `.ordered` if the order of these calls is important